# Why only one servername was redirect to https with chrome?

Tags: https, chrome

I have bulid two vhost with apache2.4(debian).

```
cat   /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.hwy.local
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_hwy.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_hwy.log combined
        <Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.test.app
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot  /home/debian9/app
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_hwy.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_hwy.log combined
        <Directory /home/debian9/app>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Typing `www.hwy.local` will not redirect `https://www.hwy.local`,Typing `www.test.app` will redirect `https://www.test.app`,why?

Comment: There is nothing in either configuration to cause a redirect. They come from elsewhere.

Comment: Without the actual domains we are not able to test this, but it doesn't come from this configuration. If you have EVER configured HSTS for this domain, the address will be translated internally in the browser, without any HTTP redirect. You can't cancel that server side, because it's designed to prevent someone else from doing that.

Answer (score 0):

as per Michael Hampton says the redirection for www.test.app does not come from the apache configuration file, have there any .htaccess file in the root direcotry of the app? there could be configured a redirect!